# Lookup between dataframes. If match exist then return count, max and min value

Tags: r, lookup

I am new to R and it seems that the solution I found to my problem takes way too much time.

I have 2 dataframes:

```
 UniqueID  colA colB
 1          x     y
 2          x     y
 3          x     y
 4          x     y
```

And

```
UniqueID   category   date
 1           a        d1
 1           a        d2
 1           b        d3
 2           c        d4
 3           a        d5
 3           a        d6
```

I want to obtain a dataframe, which later will be appended to the first one, with something like (assuming d1 < d2 and d5 < d6)

```
 UniqueID    totaloccurrences  occurrencescatA MindatecatA MaxdatecatA
 1                  3                 2             d1          d2
 2                  1                 0             0            0
 3                  2                 2             d5           d6
```

For each Id i need to count the total number of times it appears in the second dataframe, and then for count how many appearances are tied to each category, and record the earlier and latest observation.

The best I could do was using a for loop:

`iteractions <- nrow(A)
  for (i in 1:iteractions) {
       compiled[i, "ID"] <- A[i, "UniqueID"]
       compiled[i, "totaloccurrences"] <- length(B$UniqueID[B$UniqueID ==compiled[i, "ID"]])
       compiled[i, "occurrencescatA"] <- length(B$UniqueID[B$UniqueID ==compiled[i, "ID"] & B$category == "d1"]
       if  (compiled[i, "occurencescatA"] != 0) { 
            compiled[i, "MindatecatA"] <- min(B$date[B$category =="a" & B$UniqueID ==compiled[i, "ID"]])`

...

And so on for the max date, then repeat for each category.

Problem is: data frames are huge and this takes a very long time. I reckon I lack finesse, but any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse);
printDate <- function(x) format(x, "%d-%m-%Y");
left_join(
    df2 %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")),
    df1) %>%
    group_by(UniqueID) %>%
    summarise(
        totaloccurrences = n(),
        occurrencescatA = sum(category == "a"),
        MindatecatA = ifelse(occurrencescatA > 0, printDate(min(date[category == "a"])), "0"),
        MaxdatecatA = ifelse(occurrencescatA > 0, printDate(max(date[category == "a"])), "0"))
## A tibble: 3 x 5
#  UniqueID totaloccurrences occurrencescatA MindatecatA MaxdatecatA
#     <int>            <int>           <int> <chr>       <chr>
#1        1                3               2 01-05-2018  02-05-2018
#2        2                1               0 0           0
#3        3                2               2 05-05-2018  06-05-2018
```

Explanation: Perform a left-join of `df1` and `df2`, group entries by `UniqueID` and return summary quantities using `summarise`.

Note that I generated some sample `date`s to illustrate.

---

### Sample data

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
    "UniqueID  colA colB
 1          x     y
 2          x     y
 3          x     y
 4          x     y", header = T)


df2 <- read.table(text =
    "UniqueID   category   date
 1           a        01-05-2018
 1           a        02-05-2018
 1           b        03-05-2018
 2           c        04-05-2018
 3           a        05-05-2018
 3           a        06-05-2018", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am trying out this approach, but i am having some troubles - i suspect because the UniqueID column is a string - returning this message: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @rebtevye Please confirm that my sample code works with the sample data. The code also works if `UniqueID` is a `character` vector; so I'm not sure where the error originates from. I would recommend starting from my example, try to understand what every step does, and then apply the code to your real data.

Comment: Yes,i see. The code infact works with the sample, I need to figure it out

Comment: I managed to fix it, thanks for your help. I reduced df1 to a more simple entity, retaining the columns I needed. I will progressively return to the starting scenario however as I would like to understand why it wasn't working